# Camel Batch File Consumer and deleting done files

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a File Consumer which may consume more than one files per batch:

```
file://./working_dir?antInclude=*.gz&initialDelay=1000&delay=500&maxMessagesPerPoll=100&delete=true&doneFileName=${file:name}.done
```

File consumption is working fine, but it appears that only the done file for the last file gets deleted after processing.

If I reduce the `maxMessagesPerPoll` to 1, everything seems to be working as expected.

Am I doing something wrong here? I'm using Camel 2.10.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [defect](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5883), and has been resolved in later versions of Camel.

Comment: Reading that issue, and following the link to the discussion, it appears that the issue I'm facing is actually a regression introduced by the initial patches. Anyway sticking to having a batch size of 1 as upgrading is not an option ATM.